# Span next to each other in div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Im experementing with bootstrap and actually i have this html output:

[image]

What im trying to achive is that the panel is horizontal scrollable and that the two spans with `16m Wartezeit` are displayed next to each other. At the end i want to add around 5 of this spans to the panel and display them next to each other so that the user can then scroll horizontal the panel. The major problem im facing is that when i added the two spans they get a  width of 100% because of the bootstrap css. **And i dont really know how i should change the width to the actual width that is taken by the content?**
Here you can see my code in action: http://bootply.com/94690

And my html:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats"></span>
      Statistik
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <span style="text-align:center; display:inline">
      <h4 style="line-height:0">16m</h4>
      <p style="margin-bottom:0px; margin-top:4px;">Wartezeit</p>
      </span>
      <span style="text-align:center; display:inline">
      <h4 style="line-height:0">16m</h4>
      <p style="margin-bottom:0px; margin-top:4px;">Wartezeit</p>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe bootstrap's ".row" and ."col" will solve your problem. Read about [bootstrap's grid system (click).](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Something like this: [live sample here (click)](http://bootply.com/94693)

```
<div class="panel-body row" style="overflow:scroll">
      <span style="text-align:center;" class="col-xs-6">
      <h4 style="line-height:0">16m</h4>
      <p style="margin-bottom:0px; margin-top:4px;">Wartezeit</p>
      </span>
      <span style="text-align:center;" class="col-xs-6">
      <h4 style="line-height:0">16m</h4>
      <p style="margin-bottom:0px; margin-top:4px;">Wartezeit</p>
      </span>
</div>
```

However, I beg you to please stop using inline styles. Style belongs in css.

#### Update based on your comment:

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="row">
    <span class="col-xs-6">
    <span class="col-xs-6">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry but it seems not to be possible to make a panel body to a row it destroy all my other content! The next thing is that row is always 100 percent put i wanted the panel body to be more than 100%! But thanks for you try! Ill give you some points!

Comment: That isn't quite clear in your question, but it is a very simple fix. Leave the panel body alone, but give it a child that wraps the spans and make that the row. Do you understand? @JohnSmith See my updated answer.